# create 2 dimension array in C, and every cell with 512 bit size

Tags: python, c

I want to create 2d arrays, with dimension of 2 by M, and any cell in the array will have 512 bit. I was think to create something like this:

```c
#define M 1024

typedef struct {
    unsigned char public_key[2][M];
    unsigned char private_key[2][M];
} key_pair

void keygen(key *key_pair){
    srand(time(NULL))
    //
}
```

But as I can understand, every cell in this array is of size of 256 bit because is type of char, I want 512 bit, I not sure what is the simple idea to solve it.

I want have in public_key and private_key variables, a random value of 512bit in every cell. probably char I not good option, but I not able to understand what is the right way to do it, I think that I'm little a bit confused.

I have the code in Python, in Python its very simple to do it, and i want to do it in C as well.

```python
def keygen():
    SecretKey = np.zeros((2,M), dtype=object)
    PublicKey = np.zeros((2,M), dtype=object)
    for i in range(0,M):
        SecretKey[0][i] = secrets.token_bytes(512/8)
        SecretKey[1][i] = secrets.token_bytes(512/8)
        PublicKey[0][i] = secrets.token_bytes(512/8)
        PublicKey[1][i] = secrets.token_bytes(512/8)
    key = [SecretKey, PublicKey]
    return key
```

In python its work perfectly

Comment: A char is usually 8 bit, not 256 bit. Have you considered using 64 chars to form a cell of 512 bits?

Comment: Every `public_key[i][j]` element will have `8 * M` bits, so `8192` bits (assuming common 8-bit `char`).

Comment: A char is not guaranteed to be always 8 bits in c++. But it is guaranteed to be 1 byte.

Comment: And please [edit] your question to tell us about your *actual* problem. What is the underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need 512 bits? What should be 512 bits, `public_key` in total? `public_key[i]`? Or `public_key[i][j]`? And why do you think 512 bits and your arrays of arrays would solve the underlying and actual problem? Right now your question is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Oh, and `char` can be signed *or* unsigned. It's up to the compiler and can depend on many things. When dealing with individual bits, it's always best to use explicitly unsigned types.

Comment: sorry for the confusion the I did. i add some code in Python as well. In python the solution is very simple. i want to do the same think in C as well.

Comment: Don't use any other computer than those where 1 byte = 8 bits. With that established, think of bytes not bits. It would seem that you want a data type which is 64 bytes large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a data type (a structure, for example) whose size is 512 bit.
2. Create an array whose cell is the data type.

```
#include <limits.h>

#define M 1024

#define CELL_LENGTH_IN_BITS 512

struct cell_s {
    unsigned char data[(CELL_LENGTH_IN_BITS + CHAR_BITS - 1) / CHAR_BITS];
};

struct cell_s array[2][M];
```

In this example, the size of a cell may not be 512 bit if `CHAR_BITS` is not 8, but at least 512 bit.